# Android cursor headaches

Tags: android, cursor

Could someone please help me to understand why the following block of code keeps throwing this error? It's driving me crazy trying to debug this.

```
    public int getContactsCountByGroupId(int id) {
      Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM msg_group_lu WHERE group_id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
      DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);
      int retval = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("total"));
    return retval;
}
```

The dump seems to indicate this;
0 {
    total=0
}

This is telling me that there is data in column 0, but yet everytime it tries to execute the line with this code;

```
int retval = new Integer(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("total")));
```

It gives me this error;
CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with size of 1

I have tried everything I can think of to try to fix this and am completely stumped. :(

I hope someone knows what causes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try writing `c.moveToNext();` before executing the line

```
int retval = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("total"));
```

The cursor position is now -1. after executing the moveToNext command it comes to 0th position.

Comment: Wow! That was it. Thanks, khotmanish! But why on earth would the query set the cursor row index to a -1? That doesn't make any sense.